# What's the noun for a team or person that is qualified in a tournament?

Tags: nouns

A team or person that passes the qualification rounds is then a... what?

A qualifee? A qualitee?

"Qualified team" is not what I'm looking for. Neither is contender or candidate since that doesn't imply the status of qualified.

Comment: Have you looked up 'qualify' and looked for agent nouns? Doesn't 'qualifier' have the meaning you require?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A team or individual that has qualified is a

[Qualifier](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/qualifier) - One who qualifies for something, especially a contestant who qualifies for a stage in a competition.

Comment: I'm not sure that this question would be considered suitable on ELL, never mind ELU.

Comment: It works. I guess I was looking for something less ambiguous like in German: Qualifikant is the word for someone or somebody who qualified and Qualifizierung is the competition for qualifying them. I'll mark the answer as sufficient.

Comment: @PoultryMan - not ambiguous in English. A qualifier is a person who has qualified!

Comment: @Dan it is https://www.dictionary.com/browse/qualifier >a preliminary heat or contest

Comment: @PoultryMan - both senses are standard

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you’re looking for here. As previously answered "**qualifier**" is correct. However, are you trying to say that "the team is now a **participant** in the competition as they have got **through** the qualifying stages"?
**par•tic•i•pant** (pɑrˈtɪs ə pənt) 
n. a person or group that participates.
adj. participating; sharing.

Answer (score 0):

*Qualifier* should be the appropriate word for this situation.